# NodeJS HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, node.js

I'm not sure why the CSS is being ignored here. Is there something specific I need to do with NodeJS in order to be able to use CSS inside HTML? Has it got anything to do with the  tag's "type" attribute?

The NodeJS code:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response){
response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/index.html');
});
```

HTML code (index.html):

```
....
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
....
```

Comment: You need to serve your CSS also, or embed it in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Node.js code says:

*When the browser requests `/` send a copy of the file `index.html`*

You don't have any code which handles the case:

*When the browser requests `/styles.css`*.

You need to deal with that case (probably by writing something generic that matches arbitrary requests against your filesystem, which you might do by looking for a static hosting library — for example by using [the express framework](https://expressjs.com/) and its [static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)).

That said, if you are just going to serve static files, then you might as well not use Node at all and use a general webserver.

Answer (score 0):

After going through this problem, my solution to this is as follows.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/') {
    fs.readFile('menu.html', function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    });
  }
  else if (req.url === '/menu.css') {
    fs.readFile('menu.css', function(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    });
  }
}).listen(PORT);
```

It was very tough for me as a beginner to understand how to debug this problem. But using console.log(req.url) I was able to figure out this issue of serving css.

it seems that here we are addressing each request separately